# All Solutions to $ \frac{dy}{dx} = (y-1)e^x $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = (y-1)e^x $

a) Find all solutions to the above differential equation

b) Find the solution of the differential equation above that satisfies $y(0) = 5 $

c) Find the solution of the differential equation above that satisfies $y(0) =1 $

Here is what I have done:

a) $\int \frac{dy}{y-1} = \int e^x dx $

$ln|y-1| = e^x + C$

$y= Ce^{e^x} +1 $

Does the above cover all cases for the absolute value?

The division by zero case:

When $(y-1) = 0 \implies (y-1)e^x = 0 \implies (y-1) = 0 \implies y=1 $

b) $5= Ce^{e^0} + 1 \implies \frac{4}{e} = C \implies y = \frac{4}{e}e^{e^x} + 1 $

c) $ 1= Ce^{e^0} + 1 \implies C=0 \implies y = 1 $

Does this work look alright?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I do believe so, yes. You solved it in the most general way possible, I dont see why you'd lose generality.  Here is a linear solution for you I noticed right off the bat. When $y=1$ for all $x$ then $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$. You have a flat line.  This is captured in your solution as $C=0$.  You have observed this yourself in your part c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although $\ln\left(\left|y-1\right|\right)=e^x+C$ implies $y-1=\pm e^{e^{x}+C}$, both solutions can be represented as $y=1+C'e^{e^{x}}$, where $C'$ can be positive or negative. So you are right that $y=1+C'e^{e^{x}}$ covers all the cases for absolute value.